# My GPS location changes when on a call

Tags: gps, google-maps, geolocation

My GPS location is accurate in Google Maps except when I am on the phone.  It consistently changes my location to another house 5 blocks away. When I end the call it goes back to my real location. 
How can I resolve this?
Scott

Comment: May be this is your "non-GPS" location (automatic disabling of GPS while calling or you cover the GPS sensor so that it no longer finds the satellites)? Have you checked what happens if you disable GPS? Try to perform the call hands-free may be the position then doe snot change.

Comment: Now that I understand the difference between GPS and non GPS location it makes sense because it always puts me in the same wrong place when I’m on a call which must be where one of the cell towers try to locate me.